# Ergodicity of a measurable transformation on $\mathbb{T}^2$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let the dynamical system $(\mathbb{T}^2,\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{T}^2},m_{\mathbb{T^2}},T)$ where $m_{\Bbb{T}^2}=m_{\Bbb{T}} \times m_{\Bbb{T}}$ the product measure of the Lebesgue measure $m$ on the circle $\Bbb{T}$ and $$T(x,y)=(x+a,y+2x+b) \text{mod1}$$

It is not difficult to prove using Fubini's theorem that $T$ is measure preserving

> For which $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$ is $T$  ergodic?

I'm new to ergodic theory and i would appreciate any help solving this problem.

My thoughts are to use the theorem which states that:

If $f:\Bbb{T^2} \to \Bbb{T}^2$ such that $f \in L^2(\Bbb{T}^2)$ and  $f(T(x,y))=f(x,y) \Rightarrow$ $f$ is constant almost everywhere,then $T$ is ergodic.

To use this i took the Fourier expansion of $f$ in $\Bbb{T^2}$ (which converges to $f$ with respect to the $L^2$ norm) to find the form of the values $a,b$ but i could not solve it.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No need for Fubini's theorem: the derivative of $T$ has determinant 1. As for the Fourier series you need to equate the coefficients and then deduce whatever comes from there. Note that "to find the form of the values $a$, $b$" doesn't make sense, your aim should instead be to deduce whatever comes from knowing that $f\circ T$ is in $L^2$.

Comment: @John B...When i say ''the form of the values $a,b$ i mean if they must be irrational numbers or rational numbers..you are right though i did not state it correctly.Also to  determine that, i must use the Fourier expansion of $f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $f(x)=\sum_{n,m} a_{n,m} e^{2\pi i n x} e^{2\pi i n y}$ (the Fourier series of $f$).

Suppose that $f$ is $T$ invariant then

$$f=\sum_{n,m} a_{n,m} e^{2\pi i n a} e^{2\pi i m b} e^{2\pi i m y} e^{2\pi i m (3x)}$$

Since the Fourier coefficients unique. we have that $a_{n+3m,m} = a_{n,m} e^{2\pi i na } e^{2\pi i m b}$ It follows that $|a_{n+3m,m}| = |a_{n,m}|$ but the Fourier coefficients must converge to zero (parseval identity implies that $\|f\|_2^2 = \sum|a_{n,m}|^2$) It follows that $a_{n,m}=0$ for all $m\not = 0$.

We conclude that $f$ is invariant if and only if it is independent of $y$. (In other words $f$ is only defined on the first torus, and so the action is ergodic iff $a$ is irrational)

Comment: I have already solved this problem but thanks anyway..Indeed the action is ergodic iff $a$ is irrational...The ergodicity does not depend on $b$..I will accept your answer..:)

Comment: Can you also take a look at this?...This problem is much more difficult..https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612845/ergodicity-of-a-skew-product

Comment: @MariosGretsas It is a very interesting question. I post a solution.