# Explicit solution to the following functional equation

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples, functional-equations, ergodic-theory

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. I want to find a Lebesgue measurable function $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$, the functional equation $$mf(x)=h(x+a)-h(x) \pmod 1$$ does not have a measurable solution $h:[0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$.

Motivation: The main motivation is related to the following question [Ergodicity of a skew product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612845/ergodicity-of-a-skew-product). This question gives a general criterion for ergodicity of a skew product considered. I want a specific example of such a skew product, which boils down to my question above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably you recognize **directly** that for $f=0$ the map is not ergodic, right?

Comment: @JohnB yes. I am after an example of $f$ which makes the map ergodic